# How to input number in a row in an specific sheet and go to next row automatically

Tags: excel

Hi every one I have googled my problem and I had not find some thing
Basically what I want to do is insert numbers in row 1 in cell 1 to X and next time that I want to input to goes to next row automatically
Thank you so much

Comment: Your question's goal is not clear and is not described understandable. Describe it step by step in detail. How do you want to import data to it?

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is an screenshot from my excel and my Macro "https://ibb.co/hDps9yN"

Comment: I should add dialog box for cell A2 to D2,what i want is input my numbers in next raw

Comment: The photo must be embedded within the question's body. Adding tag "VBA" will be helpful for your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for six columns *(columns A through F)*.

Put the following code in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 6 Then
        Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).Select
    Else
        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

When you enter a value in **A1**, **B1** is automatically selected for the next entry, etc.  When a value is entered in **F1**, then **A2** is automatically selected *(drop down and back to the first column)*.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

You can adjust the code to handle the number of columns you require.

Comment: Thank you Ali I added your code to my file but it seems I made a mistake some where i am amatuer in coding I upload my files in this link I will be thankful if you check the file "https://www.filemail.com/d/glywwwojyopvjde" I assigned a star shape to macro, what i want is next time that i run the macros, my inputs go to next row